# Cannot remove client access rule on Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange-server

I added a client access rule to restrict ECP access.
In the document I followed, it was a.b.c.0/24, so I added it as a.b.c.d/32.

The rule didn't work.

As I struggled, I realized that I can add a new rule with the same name, I can delete the one I just added, but I cannot delete the first rule I wrote no matter what I do, I get an error that the rule could not be found.

I guess things won't go back to normal until we delete this.

Is there a way to delete it or will things get worse if I delete the directory studio related entry?

Here is two ksc

[Directory Studio View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6OAr.png)

[Error View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqBqw.png)

Comment: I have deleted the rule from here via adsiedit.msc



CN=Client Access Rules,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mu,DC=edu,DC=tr

Problem resolved.